# Java webapp : How to map/direct webapp to your BASE URL/IP?

Tags: java, spring, maven, web-applications, jetty

Typically when you create a webapp you will access your webapp when you hit the url

```
<your_IP>/<Project_name>/
```

**Example:**

**127.0.0.1/MyWebapp/**

**Question:** How do you configure your webapp to run from base URL

Example

**127.0.0.1/**

Moreover, when the browser navigates to your IP (and not your IP + name of your webapp) you can hit your webpage

**Question:** Is this a configuration file that needs to be edited in your **Application web server**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your container, but generally you will name your file `ROOT.war` or specify the context explicitly.

For example, since you've tagged this question with [[image]jetty](/questions/tagged/jetty), here is the plugin in my pom.xml for embedded testing using `mvn jetty:run`. Notice the `contextPath` element.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.25</version>
    <configuration>
        <contextPath>/</contextPath>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
        <connectors>
            <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                <port>8081</port>
                <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
            </connector>
        </connectors>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I deploy to Tomcat, I simply name my file `ROOT.war` and drop it into the `webapps` folder. Note that you'll need to move or remove the existing ROOT content from `webapps` first.

Doing this will allow you to access your application at `http[s]://<host>[:<port>]/` with no extra context needed.

Assuming you're using [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) to build your application, you can avoid manually re-naming your WAR by specifying the `finalName` in your pom.xml.

```
<build>
    <finalName>ROOT</finalName>

    [...]
</build>
```

Comment: With the exception of manually renaming the war to ROOT.war I have this same exact setup. Do you know of any configuration that will automatically rename the war - granted this works as you described